# In-app billing provisioning on a rooted device

Tags: android, security, root, in-app-billing

I'm developing an Android app that will offer in-app billing to the user to buy a certain number of coins (for example).  When this purchase is consumed, I want to store this fact by increasing a variable CoinsRemaining, for example.

A simple way to do this is to increase with variable and update it in a SharedPreference in internal memory.

However, if the device is rooted, with the user having write access to /data, surely the user can modify the preferences manually to increase this CoinsRemaining variable.

I know there is a always a trade-off between effort required to make something secure, and how valuable the protected content is etc.  Is there a more secure way to achieve this without using complicated server-side strategies?

Comment: Could you simply check with the server the value of the coinsRemaining? The code wouldn't be that complex and it would save you losing money...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use secure preferences, but encryption key also should be saved somewhere on device or in your application code. You can use `keystore` for saving encryption key in it.

Secure preferences projects: [scottyab/secure-preferences](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences/), [kovmarci86/android-secure-preferences](https://github.com/kovmarci86/android-secure-preferences/)